# Can't download Analysis Tools required for Go with Visual Studio

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am a total newbie and only just kicked off a beginners course on Go and failing at first hurdle of installation of all the bits you need to make it work so sorry if this is a dumb question. I've installed Go, Git and Visual Studio... After first installing Visual Studio I am trying to install the 12 Analysis tools for Go but everytime i try this it fails. Generally related to a "permission denied" error. Error message below. Any ideas why?

> Installing 12 tools at /Documents/go/bin   gocode   gopkgs
>   go-outline   go-symbols   guru   gorename   dlv   gocode-gomod   godef
>   godef-gomod   goreturns   golint
>
> Installing github.com/mdempsky/gocode FAILED Installing
>   github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs FAILED Installing
>   github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline FAILED Installing
>   github.com/acroca/go-symbols FAILED Installing
>   golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru FAILED Installing
>   golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename FAILED Installing
>   github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv FAILED Installing
>   github.com/stamblerre/gocode FAILED Installing
>   github.com/rogpeppe/godef FAILED Installing github.com/ianthehat/godef
>   FAILED Installing github.com/sqs/goreturns FAILED Installing
>   golang.org/x/lint/golint FAILED
>
> 12 tools failed to install.
>
> gocode: Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go get -u -v
>   github.com/mdempsky/gocode github.com/mdempsky/gocode (download)
>   package github.com/mdempsky/gocode: mkdir /Documents/go: permission
>   denied github.com/mdempsky/gocode (download) package
>   github.com/mdempsky/gocode: mkdir /Documents/go: permission denied
>
> gopkgs: Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go get -u -v
>   github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs github.com/uudashr/gopkgs
>   (download) package github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs: mkdir
>   /Documents/go: permission denied github.com/uudashr/gopkgs (download)
>   package github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs: mkdir /Documents/go:
>   permission denied

Comment: Can you execute this command `mkdir /Documents/go` to create the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use visual studio for golang so may be of limited use here if it is visual studio specific - but I've heard nothing but good things so its probably not...

I suspect the issue is that your GOPATH is set to `/Documents/go` whereas you have placed your GOPATH in the Documents folder for your user. it should probably be something like `%My Documents%/go` or the full path to that location e.g something like `/c/Users/{your user}/Documents`.

**Note: I have used nix style paths - as your output does, but when setting them via windows gui you should use windows conventions, e.g `C:\Users\...`**

To diagnose further I would first cut the ide out of the equation and jump to the command line.

type `go env` to check your paths, look particularly at GOPATH which I suspect is your problem. If it is incorrect you should change it in environment variables (google change environment variables for you windows version) - as per note above follow the conventions of the other environment variables for setting the path (windows style specification, `e.g c:\Users\`)

if `go env` doesn't work you have a bigger issue with your go install

If you are still having issues, please update your question, providing the output of `go env` as well as an outline of how you installed go (Note: I think the MSI installer takes care of it all for you)

if go env looks fine to you, another debug step would be to attempt to install one of your tools manually from the command line and see what happens, e.g:

`go get -u -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode`

but if go env doesn't work that wont either and the issue is likely that your main go binary is not in you systems `PATH` environment variable but it doesn't look like that

Comment: Yes.. it was my GOPATH route which was set to a tree that started with icloud rather than let's say Users/... from the hard drive. in a more conventional setting. Once I moved it and reset my Go Path accordingly it seemed to work. thanks for getting back and everyone's help; Just ran my first golang program so dead pleased

Comment: glad you're sorted - for some reason i saw visual studio and jumped straight to windows despite the paths suggesting otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply ensure the Git has been added to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Can you explain that further? How to do this? How does this solve the given problem?